# How to validate input custom using directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have made the following directive:

```
.directive('checkValueTypeArray', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            typeElement: '=',
            typeValue: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            var type_value = scope.typeValue;

            ngModel.$validators.required = function (v) {

                switch (type_value) {

                    case "integer":
                        status = isInt(v);
                        break;

                    case "string":
                        status = isNaN(v);
                        break;

                    case "object":
                        status = true;
                        break;

                    case "array":
                    case "array_objects":
                        status = true;
                        break;

                    case "boolean":
                        status = (v === "true" || v === "false");
                        break;

                    case "float":
                        status = isNumeric(v);
                        break;

                    case "vector2":
                        status = (v.length === 2);
                        break;

                    case "vector3":
                        status = (v.length === 3);
                        break;
                }

                return status;
            };
        }
    };
})
```

And call this directive like as:

```
<input
    ng-required="true"
    check-value-type-array
    type-value="node.type_value"
    type-element="node.type"
    ng-value="item"
    class="form-control"
    ng-change="changeArrayValue(inputValue, $index, node, $parent.$index)"
    ng-model="inputValue" type="text"
    placeholder="Value ($$node.type_value$$)"
>
```

Problem is that if `status` false, it does not input field error(color).

So, it does not work for me. When I see input in DOM Chrome, I see isolated model.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to add a `$observe` :

Have a look at the ngRequired directive from the angular.js source :

```
var requiredDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      ctrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !attr.required || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
      };

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  };
};
```